# How to use jsdoc with gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, jsdoc

How can I create a gulp command to build documentation using [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)?

I don't want to use the [gulp-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsdoc) package, as it is not maintained. And the package I had been using to call it from the command line, [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell), is on the [gulp blacklist](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json#L15).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use node's built-in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) like this:

```
var child_exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('docs', function(done) {
    child_exec('node ./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js ./lib -c ./jsdoc.json', undefined, done);
});
```

(This example assumes you have a config file `./jsdoc.json`, but it's easy to change the calling syntax.)